# Unable to commit changes in SVN - Forbidden by the server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have problem with a developer that is unable to commit change to SVN with the below error message. He has administrator access on the local machine, and also has full access to the SVN repo. I made sure he can access the files, he can open and edit changes, but he is only unable to commit. It is not an available space issue, nor access issue although it seems like one.

```
Command   Commit
Modified  C:\Users\robb\Documents\RBS\page1.html
Error     Commit failed (details below):
Error     Changing file
Error     'C:\Users\robb\RBS\page1.html
Error     is forbidden by the server
Error     Access to '/svn/RBS/!svn/ver/2/trunk/RBS/page1.html
Error     forbidden
Error     Aditional errors:
Error     CHECKOUT of
Error     'svn/RBS/!svn/ver/2/trunk/RBS/page1.html
Error     403 Forbidden
```

Comment: Most often, I see this because Subversion is case-sensitive and Windows is not. Does case of the path that his WC was checked out from match the case in the repository itself? Does the path-based authorization rule match the case of the path in the repository exactly?

Comment: "is forbidden by the server" is the strange part here.

Comment: Failed pre-commit hook?

Answer (score -1):

> He has administrator access on the local machine, and also has full
>   access to the SVN repo.

No, he does not.

This user lacks Write access to the file or the repository and you should double-check the [path-based access rules](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) that are applicable to this user. There has to be an access rule that affects this user's capability to commit or perform other Write operations to the repository.

You could read this article for an explanation of access control principles of path-based authorization in SVN: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/